# Loopback testing upload file as a user with role

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I’ve been writing tests for my loopback backend using loopback-testing project. 
The backend has set loopback-component-storage in order to provide apis to store files in the filesystem. I want to test file upload using the remote api that loopback-component-storage provides using something like this:

```
describe('Containers', function() {
   lt.it.shouldBeAllowedWhenCalledByUserWithRole(TEST_USER, someRole, 
      'POST', '/api/containers/somecontainer/upload', somefile);
});
```

But with no luck... There's no documentation about this. I don't know if it is even possible to test. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Some links:

https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-testing

https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-component-storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[loopback-testing is currently deprecated.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/loopbackjs/w038RvqHeYI))

You should consider using [supertest](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest) instead. It relies on [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent), and allows you to perform http requests on your REST api and assert on response objects.

Then, you can use the [`attach` method of super-agent](http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#multipart-requests) to build a multipart-form-data request that can contain a file.

Code using mocha for describing test looks then like this:

```
var request = require('supertest');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = require('./setup-test-server-for-test.js');

function json(verb, url) {
    return request(app)[verb](url)
    .set('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
};

describe("User",function() {
    it("should be able to add an asset to the new project", function(done){
       var req = json('post', '/api/containers/someContainer/upload?access_token=' + accessToken)
       .attach("testfile","path/to/your/file.jpg")
       .expect(200)
       .end(function(err, res){
            if (err) return done(err);
            done();
       });
    });

    it("should have uploaded the new asset to the project folder", function(done){
        fs.access('/path/to/your/file.jpg', fs.F_OK, function(err){
            if (err) return done(err);
            done();
        });
    });
};
```